# Remove element from list of lists during loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data structure `info` (a list of lists?) that I am constructing as follows:

```
pages     = [12, 41, 50, 111, 1021, 121]
bookCodes = ['M', 'P', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'M']
sentences = ['THISISASENTENCE',
             'ANDHEREISONEMOREEXAMP',
             'ALLFROMDIFFERENTBOOKS',
             'ANDFROMDIFFERENTPAGES',
             'MOSLTYTHESAMELENGTHS',
             'THISISSHORT'
             ]
info = list(zip(bookCodes, pages, sentences))
```

I am then iterating over this list (of zipped lists) on letter at a time. As some sentences are shorter than others (e.g. `THISISSHORT`) I reach the final element before other sentences. In this case I want mask this element from future iterations completely **but I don't want to filter it before I start my loop**.

```
import random

letters_read = 0

for i in range(21):
    random.shuffle(info)
    for b, p, s in info:
        if len(s) <= i+1:
            print("End of sentence reached at position %s. Sentence: %s" % (i, s))
            continue    
        letters_read += 1
```

I am currently using `continue` to skip over elements where this is the case, and print a message to indicate the sentence that has reach its end. However, this will continue iterating over this element until the end of the loop. **I want to exclude such elements from further iterations.**

I have ~ `10,000` sentences in my list, and these can be as large as `2000` characters, so I am assuming that by masking such sentences from future iterations rather than skipping will increase the efficiency of my script.

Is it possible to remove/mask an element from this data structure during iteration? I've tried using `info.remove(i)` and `del info[i]`, but this doesn't work (seeing as this is not a list).

---

**Output**:

```
End of sentence reached at position 10. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 11. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 12. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 13. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 14. Sentence: THISISASENTENCE
End of sentence reached at position 14. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 15. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 15. Sentence: THISISASENTENCE
End of sentence reached at position 16. Sentence: THISISASENTENCE
End of sentence reached at position 16. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 17. Sentence: THISISASENTENCE
End of sentence reached at position 17. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 18. Sentence: THISISASENTENCE
End of sentence reached at position 18. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 19. Sentence: THISISASENTENCE
End of sentence reached at position 19. Sentence: MOSLTYTHESAMELENGTHS
```

**Desired output**:

---

```
End of sentence reached at position 10. Sentence: THISISSHORT
End of sentence reached at position 14. Sentence: THISISASENTENCE
End of sentence reached at position 19. Sentence: MOSLTYTHESAMELENGTHS
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the element from the data structure during iteration? Just `filter` them out before iterating should suffice?

Comment: what exactly is your desired output for this example?

Comment: @fugu What you want to do is not a good programing practise (if i understand your needs properly). Modifying a list as you iterate over it, is not advisable. And I fail to see why you do not want to modify it before looping.

Comment: Now...... looks like XY problem. You want to be efficient, and you think that masking out the elements are more efficient. No, there are a simpler and more efficient method.

Comment: @user202729 - I'm completely open to the idea that my idea is not maximally efficient and could achieved more elegantly, efficiently or Pythonically. Any advice is welcome and appreciated

Comment: What about filtering them after the loop?

Comment: @user202729 - I do **not** want to filter out these elements prior to filtering, but iterate over them until I reach their end, and then not iterate over that element in future iterations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make copy of original list and then iterate over new copy and remove the items from original list

```
for item in list(original_list):
  ...
  original_list.remove(item)
```

In your case, code will look like below

```
total_read = 0

for i in range(21):
    random.shuffle(info)
    for index, value in enumerate(list(info)):
        b, p, s = value
        if len(s) <= i+1:
            print("Overshot! Shouldn't see this sentence anymore: %s" % (s))
            info.pop(index)
        print s[:i+1], i, s

        total_read += len(s[i + 1])
```

Comment: Can be shorter as `original_list[:]` or `original_list*1`.

Comment: Note: `original_list.remove(item)` is an Θ(n) operation. Therefore using it is **less** efficient than `filter`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use del to delete the item from the zipped list

```
for i in range(21):
    q=0
    for p, b, s in info:
        if len(s)<=i+1:
            print(f'Overshot! Remove this element {s} {q}')
            del info[q]
        print(f"{s[:i+1]}, {i}, {s}")
        total_read += len(s[i+1])
        q+=1
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but appears to be slower than the solution provided by MA1

Answer (score 0):

Sanitize your input first and then loop over it:

```
sentences = ['THISISASENTENCE',
             'ANDHEREISONEMOREEXAMP',
             'ALLFROMDIFFERENTBOOKS',
             'ANDFROMDIFFERENTPAGES',
             'MOSLTYTHESAMELENGTHS',
             'THISISSHORT'
             ]
max_len = len(max(sentences, key=len))  # kudos ZachGates
print max_len  # 21
sentences = filter(lambda x: len(x)==max_len, sentences)
print sentences  # ['ANDHEREISONEMOREEXAMP', 'ALLFROMDIFFERENTBOOKS', 'ANDFROMDIFFERENTPAGES']
```

Now you can proceed as you did.

Comment: You don't need the first `lambda`; `len` will work on its own: `max_len = len(max(sentences, key=len))`.

Comment: @ZachGates Thanks !

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I'm trying to do - see update which is hopefully clearer. I want to iterate over all elements, but once the end of a sentence is reached I want that to be the last time the sentence is iterated over.

Comment: @fugu it would help to give us the desired output for the example you have in the question. A seasoned SO user like you should already know that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the list and iterate through the copy and delete the item from orginal.

```
for i in info[:]:
  info.remove(i)
```